# Classification of regular connected covering spaces.

Tags: group-theory, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I read the following:

> By classical covering space theory, the connected, regular covers of a $CW-\text{complex}$ are classified by the quotients of its fundamental group.

Aren't connected covering spaces of $X$ classified by **subgroups** of $\pi_1(X)?$

I don't understand why the author used the word quotient group instead of a subgroup! Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe regular covers correspond to normal subgroups, and thus to quotients by those normal subgroups.

Comment: Yes regular covers correspond to normal subgroups so why not saying that, why the quotients by these subgroups and not the subgroups themselves, this is exactly my question.

Comment: I guess it saves one word to say “quotients” rather than “normal subgroups.” Or maybe the author is used to thinking about the quotient groups rather than the normal subgroups.

Comment: Also notice that the commutator subgroup is normal but need not be abelian while the quotient by the commutator subgroup is an abelian group. So you see that normal subgroups and quotients don't share the same properties.

Comment: It depends on whether you work in the pointed or unpointed category (which essentially determines how many automorphisms you allow). In the pointed category the classification depends on subgroups. In the unpointed category the classification depends on conjugacy classes of subgroups, and hence also to quotients.